# Impact of number of physical partitions on Cosmos DB performance

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Suppose we start with an empty Cosmos DB container with 4000 RU/s provisioned throughput (i.e. there will only be one physical partition initially), using `/id` as partition key (so each logical partition contains exactly one document). As the container grows and approaches or exceeds the maximum physical partition size of 50 GB, the container will eventually split into multiple physical partitions, and the throughput will be split up between these partitions accordingly.

1. Is it then necessary to provide `n * 4000 RU/s` (where `n` is the number of physical partitions) to maintain the performance of the collection when it was still a single physical partition?
2. More generally, how does the number of physical partitions (i.e., splitting the throughput) impact the performance on point reads, writes and (cross-partition) queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RU/sec allocation will indeed be split across physical partitions. This is definitely something to be aware of, as partition-splits *can* result in an unexpected RU/sec drop (or throttling). Keep in mind though:

- you might or might not experience issues, if your database traffic is normally-distributed across partitions
- you might or might not even be approaching RU/sec limitations aside from burst/max traffic - it's important to monitor `429` (throttle) frequency to determine when/if scaling is needed.

But yes, if you allocated 4000/sec and then, due to capacity, the container was split into two physical partitions, the RU/sec would be divided across the two physical partitions, requiring you to (potentially) increase overall RU/sec to deal with this.

As for point-reads: given that you have to provide a partition-key value (in your case `/id`), there is no performance impact: still 1 RU for a 1K doc. For cross-partition queries, your RU cost will likely increase, when the query has to go beyond the first partition searched.

Comment: Just to clarify re point reads: if the throughput were something lower like 400 RU/s,  reading a document > 200 KB would cause throttling (only) when the container is split, is that correct?

Comment: @MoB. - you are only throttled if you run out of RU in a given one-second period. A single point read won't cost you more than a few RU, regardless of size - just that the 1KB read = 1RU thing is a published reference cost on a read - it doesn't just scale up linearly. Run a point read and measure the resulting RU.